# Open with explorer feature does not work in SharePoint2010 on Windows XP x64 clients

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, open-with-explorer

Our SharePoint is 2010 and 'Open with explorer' feature of document library does not work in clients that have Windows XP x64 even with IE x86. What should we do?

Best regards

Comment: Open with IE and not Chrome

Comment: yes I tried with ie 8

Answer (score 0):

I think you got this error when you are trying to open File Explorer.

> We’re having a problem opening this location in File Explorer, Add
>   this web site to your Trusted sites list and try again

This problem might occur because of

- Desktop experience feature was not installed.
- Desktop experience feature was installed,but the web client service stopped.
- Microsoft Office 2007/2010/2013 is not installed

To overcome this issue you can check this [We’re having a problem opening this location in File Explorer, Add  this web site to your Trusted sites list and try again](https://blog.devoworx.net/2015/03/23/were-having-a-problem-opening-this-location-in-file-explorer-add-this-web-site-to-your-trusted-sites-list-and-try-again/)

If the WebClient has been started, you should check the following

- Install office 64X version on XP 64, and Office 32x on XP 86X.

Also installing SharePoint Designer 64x should solve this issue

for more details, [you check Upload Multiple Documents disabled within Document Library in SharePoint](https://blog.devoworx.net/2014/11/07/upload-multiple-documents-is-disabled-in-document-library/)

Comment: the windows is xp x64 not windows server

Comment: in your issue it's working for all operating system else Windows XP ??!

Comment: my answer is to allow this work for all operating system you should configure it in your SharePoint server !! you got my point

Comment: @maria1368 check my updated answer that hope to help you

Comment: yes it's working for all operating system else Windows XP

Comment: is the office has been installed on these PC , also what's the error message that shown to you ? or it just disabled ?!